# Pass arrays from JS by reference for WASM to edit?

Tags: assemblyscript

What's the best way to pass and return arrays of floats in AssemblyScript?

Can I pass an array form JS (by reference) for WASM to edit?

```
export function nBodyForces(data: f64[], result: f64[]): void {}
```

Below is what I have now.  Ignore the implementation details, and it's returning 2000, then incrementing it to 8000ish.

What's the best way to return an array of new values?

```
export function nBodyForces(data: f64[]): f64[] {
  // Each body has x,y,z,m passed in.
  if (data.length % bodySize !== 0) return new Array<f64>(10);
  const numBodies: i32 = data.length / bodySize;

  // return a 3-force x,y,z vector for each body
  let ret: f64[] = new Array<f64>(numBodies * forceSize);  

  /**
   * Calculate the 3-vector each unique pair of bodies applies to each other.
   * 
   *   0 1 2 3 4 5
   * 0   x x x x x
   * 1     x x x x
   * 2       x x x
   * 3         x x
   * 4           x
   * 5
   * 
   * Sum those forces together into an array of 3-vector x,y,z forces
   */

  // For all bodies:
  for (let i: i32 = 0; i < numBodies; i++) {
    // Given body i: pair with every body[j] where j > i
    for (let j: i32 = i + 1; i < numBodies; j++) {
      // Calculate the force the bodies apply to one another
      const bI: i32 = i * 4
      const bJ: i32 = j * 4
      let f: f64[] = twoBodyForces(
        // b0
        data[bI], data[bI+1], data[bI+2], data[bI+3], // x,y,z,m
        // b1
        data[bJ], data[bJ+1], data[bJ+2], data[bJ+3], // x,y,z,m
      );
      // Add this pair's force on one another to their total forces applied x,y,z
      // body0
      ret[bI] = ret[bI] + f[0];    
      ret[bI+1] = ret[bI+1] + f[1];    
      ret[bI+2] = ret[bI+2] + f[2];
      // body1    
      ret[bJ] = ret[bJ] + f[0];    
      ret[bJ+1] = ret[bJ+1] + f[1];    
      ret[bJ+2] = ret[bJ+2] + f[2];
    }
  }
  // For each body, return the summ of forces all other bodies applied to it.
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For faster interop with JS I recommend use typed arrays if this possible

```
export const FLOAT64ARRAY_ID = idof<Float64Array>();
export function nBodyForces(data: Float64Array): Float64Array { ... }
```

And later on JavaScript side:

```
const loader = require("assemblyscript/lib/loader");
const imports = {};
const wasm = await loader.instantiateStreaming(fetch("optimized.wasm"), imports);

const dataArray = [... your data ...]
const dataRef = wasm.__retain(wasm.__allocArray(wasm.FLOAT64ARRAY_ID, dataArray));

const resultRef = wasm.nBodyForces(dataRef);
const resultArray = wasm.__getFloat64Array(resultRef);

// release ARC resources
wasm.__release(dataRef);
wasm.__release(resultRef);

console.log("result: " + resultArray);
```

Comment: Ok, intresting.  It looks like this is alloc/copy/dealloc of memory.  Is there a way to do this with shared linear memory?  I'm trying to go DomThread -> WebWorker -> Wasm -> and back.

Comment: In Chrome and FF, I get "wasm.__allocArray" is not a function.  I tried runtime full and half (and default).  I'm using `WebAssembly.instantiate(msg.wasmModule, importObj)` to instantiate the wasm in a web worker.

Comment: You should use "assemblyscript/lib/loader" instead `WebAssembly.instantiate`. Loader expose `__allocArray`, `__retain` `__release` and etc and also wrapped `instantiateStreaming`/`instantiate`. See first line in my example

Comment: I saw that.  Is there no solution without require() and webpack?

Comment: You could try something like this:

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/assemblyscript/assemblyscript/lib/loader/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      const wasm = instantiateStreaming("<your module>.wasm");
       ...
    });
</script>

But I recommend using webpack or rollup

Comment: Line 292 doesn't like undefined "exports".  `exports.instantiate = instantiate;`  It's a web worker.  Making a web worker loader would be a cool feature.  Anyways, appreciate the help :-)